# I am not getting gps coordinates from NETWORK_PROVIDER sometimes

Tags: android, gps

LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

```
    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

    //init();

}

/* Class My Location Listener */

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

{

@Override

public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

{

    //_pd.dismiss();

loc.getLatitude();

loc.getLongitude();

String Text = "My current location is: " +"Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +"Longitud ="  + loc.getLongitude();
txtInfo.setText(Text);

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),Text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)

{

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

}

@Override

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)

{

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)

{

}
}
```

this is my code....SOmetimes i get gps coordinates and sometimes i dont why is it happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting Geo Fix using GPS requires long time, hence you need to switch between Wirless network provider and GPS to get Geo coordinates reliably. It is good Idea to first poll the Wireless network and if not enabled/available then fallback to GPS provider.

Good Reference : [Android-location-providers-gps-network-passive](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslocationmaps/226-android-location-providers-gps-network-passive)

Answer (score 0):

This is because some locations doesn't show the latitude and longitude in android. This is not an big problem you just check your lat and lng returns null or not. If it returns null you just show a simple message there is no lat and lng at this location.